# Winsock reading remote data (CMD)

Tags: c++, winsock, recv

I have a server (remote) which redirects your shell for the client (remote), the client side used netcat or telnet for communication.
I am developing the client side for use with windows, but I'm having problems when receiving data from the server, they come incomplete and also I can not send more than 2 times commands to the server.

the application should send remote commands to the shell (send) and receive data (recv) until the client wishes to leave.
the problem is to receive the full data from the server ...

what should be done to improve this application?

```
while (1)
{
    //READ
    memset(pbuf, 0, sizeof(pbuf));
    iResult = recv(client[iD].socket, pbuf, sizeof(pbuf) - 1, 0);
    if (iResult < 0)
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            continue;
        }

        printf("recv error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
    {
        printf("disconnected\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++)
        {
            std::cout << pbuf[i];
        }
        memset(pbuf, 0, sizeof(pbuf));

        //SEND
        memset(key_buffer, 0, sizeof(key_buffer));
        fgets(key_buffer, sizeof(key_buffer) - 1, stdin);
        if (!strcmp(key_buffer, "exit"))
            break;
        iResult = send(client[iD].socket, key_buffer, sizeof(key_buffer) - 1, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            CLEAN_UP();
            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```